# Returning XML from Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 7 instead of JSON, and Produces set to XML returns a 406

Tags: xml, asp.net-core, odata

I'm creating a little OData api for clients which require XML. I've created this in Core 2.2 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 7.2.1

The controller looks a little like this

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Produces("application/atom+xml")] // THIS BREAKS IT
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ODataController
{
    private ReportContext _db;

    public TestController(ReportContext context)
    {
        _db = context;
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable Get() => _db.Tests;
}
```

Note the "Produces" attributes, if this is removed or set to "application/json" the Get works fine, but if I add application/xml or application/atom+xml I get a 406. Is there a way to return XML instead of JSON?

Comment: Does your client who calls the endpoints sends `Accept: application/atom+xml` header? Usually client and server negotiate the content. Client may send something like `Accept: application/xml, application/atom+xml, application/json` and the server response with one of these (usually prefers the first one of the list which the server supports)

Comment: atom+xml or xml I believe, just not json

Comment: Any solution to this problem in the meanwhile? AFAIK the atom-xml is not standardized and therefore its support was removed from OData V4.